# HttpURLConnection getResponseMessage() language and codification

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am writing an android library, which uses [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for implementing a REST client. When the getResponseMessage() is called, a string with the error code and response message is returned. The problem I cannot resolve is that this message is returned in Spanish using a codification other than UTF-8. AFAIK, everything in the computer is configured to use English, OS X, Android Studio, etc. Does anyone know how to change this to English? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

1) Android minimum API level 15, target 22.

2) My main problem is with the language, not with codification. If I understood right, Strings in Java are always internally in UTF-16 and I change to UTF-8 when needed. Sorry.

3) When debugging, the error code member variable (errorResponse) of the HttpURLConnection instance has a -1 value, and the instance error message variable member (errorMessage) is null, so both are empty.

4) My computer has region Spain, and primary language English (US). The phone is in English. Default locale before getting the response message is "en_US".

5) The source code for HttpURLConnection is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java), and getResponseCode() seems to don't translate the message. I don't know what else can I do to solve this mystical issue :) .

Comment: please include your api code

Comment: getResponseMessage() -> "Returns the response message returned by the remote HTTP server.". The server talks spanish. You can convert to UTF-8 with byte[] myByteArray = myString.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8); String utf8String = new String(myByteArray, Charsets.UTF_8)

Comment: @Philipp E, We have checked the server and everything seems fine and in English. My guess is that the HttpURLInstance is generating the message on-the-fly, but I cannot understand why language is Spanish.

Comment: HttpURLConnection won't translate or create any server responses. Our servers takes the client language from the request headers and uses this language for the response. If there is no language specified in the header the server will respond with its default language. 405 means "Method not allowed". This a auto-generated message and normally not handled by the server. You should ask the responsable server guy.

Comment: @PhilippE We have debugged server raw responses using Postman, Chrome in debug mode and curl, and the three of them showed that the server is responding in English _italic_HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed_italic_. However, HttpURLConnection.getResponseMessage() in two phones is returning _italic_M�todo No Permitido_italic_ and in another two phones _italic_Método No Permitido_italic_, all are Spanish phones with language set to US. It seems to me HttpURLConnection is translating the message depending on the phone configuration. Thanks a lot for your feedback :)

Comment: I wanted to be sure that the server is not using/sending anything other than English. I am showing this message only for debugging porpuses at the client, and this is the only one not in English, so it not really a problem at all. I will try to look at the source code of the HttpURLConnection class in Android, and if a came with a solution I will post it here.